# What's the correct way to strip repeated whitespace in an Unicode string?

Tags: internationalization, regex, unicode, localization

I am trying to “serialize” a string, removing the unnecessary repeated whitespace, if any.

Will ...

- Substituting `\p{Z}+` with an empty string if at the start or the end of a string,
- Substituting `\p{Z}+` with a single space  otherwise.

... work for any language?

I am almost sure this works with Latin based languages. But is it for others?

Comment: You can't get a warranty here.  Do count on some rainy day some string having, say, U+200F in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched spaces with `\1` or `$1`

```
^\p{Z}+|\p{Z}+$|(\p{Z})\p{Z}+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bP0xU1/3)